# Using the Robot class in Java to simulate "Fn" key press

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm trying to write a small program that makes the backlight of my laptop's keyboard flash whenever I receive an email/text/other type of message.
I'm trying to use Java's Robot class to do this.

My problem so far is that I cannot seem to find the keycode for the "Fn" key.

Answer (score 5):

Java generally does not recognize multimedia key strokes (and Fn is generally considered non-standard keyboard key) as valid ones in its inbuilt libraries and will return 0 on non-standard `keystroke event`.

But you can get your key by using [Intellitype](https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/) library for non-standard keys and also as possible work-around for the input.