# How to simulate function key (enable FN key) press

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-events, keyevent

I am trying to simulate my function keys, however, the KeyEvent class does not have a name for the function enable key. I tried this [program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java), but it didn't give me any name of what the function key is.

My code for pressing the key:

```
package myCode;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class KeyboardLights {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            int keyCodeFn = KeyEvent.VK_F; // Don't know what the FN key is
            int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_F4;
            r.keyPress(keyCodeFn);
            r.keyPress(keyCode);
            r.keyRelease(keyCodeFn);
            r.keyRelease(keyCode);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any "FN" key in the keyevent page, so does anyone know how I can simulate the FN enable key

It is regarding the FN key in the bottom left corner:

[image]

Comment: do you need to press fn for you f keys to work normally?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes

Comment: okay and it does not work if you simply use only the F4 key? id think that this would call the function of f4 without the need to press fn

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I need to use FN + F5 in order to for example increase my volume

Comment: then your previous answer should have been no... maybe you can use this in java: http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/mac-os-x/how-i-emulate-pressing-fn-key-mac-os-x-keyboard-using-applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some solution was proposed here:

**[Using the Robot class in Java to simulate "Fn" key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286724/using-the-robot-class-in-java-to-simulate-fn-key-press)**

and some thoughts about that problem were mentioned here:

[Java Interface for Multimedia Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689948/java-interface-for-multimedia-keys)